# How to call a jsp file from a controller in Hybris?

Tags: jsp, model-view-controller, sap-commerce-cloud

Could you please help me and explain how should call a jsp view (jsp file) from a controller? I know how to do this in a traditional way (just: return "appropriteJspFileName"). In Hybris, I was adviced to use the following code:

```
private static final String PAGE_ID = "someId";
```

and in a get-method (in the controller):

```
final ContentPageModel page = getContentPageForLabelOrId(PAGE_ID);
storeCmsPageInModel(model, page);
return getViewForPage(page);
```

However I have no idea how to join the above with the jsp file, e.g. its name. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Each Page is associated with a *PageTemplate* type & that has an attribute *frontendTemplateName* - if you look in the example impexes you will see how that is used to reference the JSP

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make use of the `getViewForPage`, then you also need to make use of the cms system and create the apropriate items there (usually done in impex). A jsp file can be linked to a template through the `frontendTemplateName` field. It's then possible to create pages based on this template and add content slots to that page.

This example creates a productDetailsPageTemplate that points to a jsp in the product/productLayout2Page folder:

```
INSERT_UPDATE PageTemplate; $contentCV[unique = true]; uid[unique = true]                   ; name                                      ; frontendTemplateName                    ; restrictedPageTypes(code); active[default = true]
                          ;                          ; ProductDetailsPageTemplate           ; Product Details Page Template             ; product/productLayout2Page              ; ProductPage
```

**Alternatively**, you could skip the cms part and just return the location to the jsp file

Example:

`return "pages/account/accountLoginPage";`